# mod_rewrite results in err_too_many_redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?u=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^albums/(.*)$ albums.php?gallery=$1 [NC]
```

The rule about the user page (user.php) works, but the rule about the albums page (albums.php) causes this error:

> err_too_many_redirects

Comment: In the user line put L near NC, [L,NC] that would be the first mistake, the same goes for album. Or replace nc with L. Bottom rule, remove { bracket

Comment: Tried, but it didn't work. As for the bracket, it was my mispelling here, not in the original code, just corrected it.

Comment: Your two rules on the bottom conflict. You redirect everything to user.php and then do album stuff, why? Leave album, and treat it inside user.php

Comment: Just trying to get "neat" links, mysite/John instead of mysite/user.php?u=John, which works, and mysite/albums/John instead of mysite/albums.php?gallery=John, which doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: You can have a single routing file, and build your pretty urls logic from there. With the rulse you have, its a redirect loop

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: I have two domains on one server, one of them is add-on, where this rule is situated, and there's a rule for both domains, which is read like this:                                                                                                ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php

IndexIgnore *

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your rules like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^albums/(.*)$ albums.php?gallery=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?u=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: The rule began to work, but now the album page with the pretty URL can't be properly loaded, it can't find images, css and javascripts linked to the page.

Comment: @Gene To fix css,js and other relative links on the rewritten url, add a base tag to the head of your document **<base href="/">**

Comment: Thanks starkeen, you helped me a lot. But the base tag I had to write this way <base href="../">